# How can I add in htaccess accept multiple slash and non slash urls in single line

Tags: .htaccess

How can I accept slash and non-slash url with single line in Rewrite Rule?

```
RewriteRule ^clientpanel$ clientarea.php [L,NC]
```

urls: website.com/clientpanel and website.com/clientpanel/

Answer (score 0):

You can use something along the lines of:

```
`RewriteRule ^(?:clientpanel(\/?))$ clientarea.php [L,NC]`
```

---

Check out the htaccess rule at [htaccess.madewithlove.be](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=c176ded2-f9d1-5a1b-8f72-9dd5615069c1) and what the regex is doing at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/dv9DDp/2)